# react example fails with: TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Tags: reactjs

i found this tutorial:
https://blog.logrocket.com/beyond-rest-using-websockets-for-two-way-communication-in-your-react-app-884eff6655f5

for a websocket example in react and it does not seem to work out of the box.

```
tmp/connect4-master$ ls
client  LICENSE  package.json  README2.md  README.md  server.js  yarn.lock





tmp/connect4-master$ npm install

> nodemon@1.18.4 postinstall tmp/connect4-master/node_modules/nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN connect4@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN connect4@1.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 341 packages from 205 contributors and audited 2499 packages in 7.897s
found 0 vulnerabilities






tmp/connect4-master$ npm run dev

> connect4@1.0.0 dev tmp/connect4-master
> concurrently --kill-others-on-fail "yarn server" "yarn client"

yarn run v1.10.1
yarn run v1.10.1
$ nodemon server.js
$ cd client && yarn start
[0] [nodemon] 1.18.4
[0] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[0] [nodemon] watching: *.*
[0] [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
$ react-scripts start
[1] /bin/sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[1] yarn client exited with code 1
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[0] yarn server exited with code null
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! connect4@1.0.0 dev: `concurrently --kill-others-on-fail "yarn server" "yarn client"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the connect4@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     .npm/_logs/2018-10-21T15_41_34_742Z-debug.log





tmp/connect4-master$ npm install react react-dom react-scripts
npm WARN connect4@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN connect4@1.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ react-dom@16.5.2
+ react@16.5.2
added 7 packages from 3 contributors and audited 2519 packages in 3.218s
found 0 vulnerabilities






tmp/connect4-master$ npm run dev

> connect4@1.0.0 dev tmp/connect4-master
> concurrently --kill-others-on-fail "yarn server" "yarn client"

yarn run v1.10.1
yarn run v1.10.1
$ nodemon server.js
$ cd client && yarn start
[0] [nodemon] 1.18.4
[0] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[0] [nodemon] watching: *.*
[0] [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
$ react-scripts start
[0] Listening on port 1337...
[1] 
[1] Set target browsers: >0.2%, not dead, not ie <= 11, not op_mini all
[1] 
[0] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[0] [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[0] Listening on port 1337...
[1] Starting the development server...
[1] 
[1] Compiled successfully!
[1] 
[1] You can now view connect4 in the browser.
[1] 
[1]   Local:            http://localhost:3000/
[1]   On Your Network:  http://192.168.10.116:3000/
[1] 
[1] Note that the development build is not optimized.
[1] To create a production build, use yarn build.
[1]
```

and now the error:

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance
_nonIterableSpread
node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/nonIterableSpread.js:2

  1 | export default function _nonIterableSpread() {
> 2 |   throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance");
  3 | }

_toConsumableArray
node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/toConsumableArray.js:5

  2 | import iterableToArray from "./iterableToArray";
  3 | import nonIterableSpread from "./nonIterableSpread";
  4 | export default function _toConsumableArray(arr) {
> 5 |   return arrayWithoutHoles(arr) || iterableToArray(arr) || nonIterableSpread();
  6 | }

App/<
src/App.js:24

  21 |   this.setState(...self.state, {board: board})
  22 | });
  23 | this.state.socket.on('color', color => {
> 24 |   this.setState(...self.state, {color: color})
     | ^  25 | });
  26 | this.state.socket.on('turn', player => {
  27 |   if (player === this.state.color) {
```

wherer did the author, or i, go wrong?

the interesting thing is that the game shows for a split second in the first browser tab and then gets replaced with the error.

Comment: Seems like state isn't an object, without seeing any actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You made no mistake, I tryed the demo and it failed to compile exactly like you.

remove ...self.state,  after each setState( and you should be good to go.

The author probably changed his mind and replaced a previous instruction by SetState and forgot there was one less parameter.

PS: if you find out what the underscore character (_) => means in Board.js please tell me.
I'm also a newbie but could not find nowhere in the whole google world a mention of an underscore to be used with arrow parameters ... but he does and it works.

Comment: It's usually a thing to say "I don't care about this parameter". You can see the pattern in Apollo's docs, for example

`updateNetworkStatus: (_, { isConnected }, { cache }) => {`

(from https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/state.html).

Doesn't make sense in this author's context though, probably could have just left it out completely.